# Passing Tuple or List of addresses in Web3.Py to Deploy contract

Tags: python, python-3.x, solidity, web3py

So I'm trying to deploy a smart contract which requires as part of its constructor function a list of addresses. I am using the deployment script and passing it a tuple of hexadecimal strings at no avail. I've tried lists of strings, tuples of bytes, etc. If anyone can tell me what data type I need to pass into this smart contract for a list of addresses that would be amazing.
See here my deployment script:

```
from brownie import accounts, config, Turtles, network
from web3 import Web3 as web3


def deploy_turtles():
    # Grabbing an account from 0th index of Brownie's ganache default wallets
    account = get_account()
    address1 = web3.toChecksumAddress(0x4A40E425A8D1EE6279F860D8FD5DB3D3661558D6)
    address2 = web3.toChecksumAddress(0xA9873C4C5FBD0196D0FBA2E50A3EEE216C4D6780)

    addresses = (address1, address2)
    turtle_deployed = Turtles.deploy(
        "Turtles",
        "Turtle",
        "ipfs://bafybeiczsscdsbs7ffqz55asqdf3smv6klcw3gofszvwlyarci47bgf354/",
        [100, 10, 20000, 20, 10, 1655480363, 1655473254, 100],
        "ea58dfa481a0c08b4af0417e3f62244215a1ab1eae0a100da48407be5cdd94b7",
        addresses,
        [10, 15],
        addresses,
        700,
        {"from": account},
        publish_source=True,
    )
```

And below you can see the smart contract I am trying to deploy along with its relevant constructor:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";
import "./ERC721AWithRoyalties.sol";

contract Turtles is Ownable, ERC721AWithRoyalties, Pausable, PaymentSplitter {
    string public _baseTokenURI;

    bytes32 public _merkleRoot;

    uint256 public _price;
    uint256 public _presalePrice;
    uint256 public _maxSupply;
    uint256 public _maxPerAddress;
    uint256 public _presaleMaxPerAddress;
    uint256 public _publicSaleTime;
    uint256 public _preSaleTime;
    uint256 public _maxTxPerAddress;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _purchases;

    event EarlyPurchase(
        address indexed addr,
        uint256 indexed atPrice,
        uint256 indexed count
    );
    event Purchase(
        address indexed addr,
        uint256 indexed atPrice,
        uint256 indexed count
    );

    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        string memory baseTokenURI, // baseTokenURI - 0
        uint256[] memory numericValues, // price - 0, presalePrice - 1, maxSupply - 2, maxPerAddress - 3, presaleMaxPerAddress - 4, publicSaleTime - 5, _preSaleTime - 6, _maxTxPerAddress - 7
        bytes32 merkleRoot,
        address[] memory payees,
        uint256[] memory shares,
        address royaltyRecipient,
        uint256 royaltyAmount
    )
```

```
Updated: See error below ->
Running 'scripts/deploy.py::main'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 48, in main
    deploy_turtles()
  File "./scripts/deploy.py", line 13, in deploy_turtles
    turtle_deployed = Turtles.deploy(
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 549, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "brownie/network/account.py", line 509, in deploy
    data = contract.deploy.encode_input(*args)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 579, in encode_input
    data = format_input(self.abi, args)
  File "brownie/convert/normalize.py", line 20, in format_input
    raise type(e)(f"{abi['name']} {e}") from None
ValueError: constructor '['0x4a40E425a8D1EE6279f860d8fd5db3D3661558d6', '0xa9873c4c5FBd0196d0fbA2e50a3eEe216C4D6780']' - '['0x4a40E425a8D1EE6279f860d8fd5db3D3661558d6', '0xa9873c4c5FBd0196d0fbA2e50a3eEe216C4D6780']' is not a valid ETH address
```

Answer (score 0):

Ur addresses needs to be in a **checkSum** format.

Do this:

```
address1=web3.toChecksumAddress(*your address*)
address2=web3.toChecksumAddress(*your address*)
```

EDIT:

```
turtle_deployed = Turtles.deploy(
        "Turtles",
        "Turtle",
        "ipfs://bafybeiczsscdsbs7ffqz55asqdf3smv6klcw3gofszvwlyarci47bgf354/",
        [100, 10, 20000, 20, 10, 1655480363, 1655473254, 100],
        "ea58dfa481a0c08b4af0417e3f62244215a1ab1eae0a100da48407be5cdd94b7",
        addresses,
        [10, 15],
        addresses,  <-- **THIS is suppose to be an Address, not a list of Address**
        700,
        {"from": account},
        publish_source=True,
    )
```

The last addresses input need to be a single address, not a list of addresses

Comment: Hi I did edit to add this and yet am getting the same error. I have added the error as well just realized it was not there.

Comment: I see the problem, editing my answer so u can see whats wrong